# greasemonkey v3.8 @exclude does nothing

Tags: greasemonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Helloworld
// @namespace   https://www.sample.com
// @exclude     https://www.sample.com/php/*
// ==/UserScript==
alert("HELLO WORLD!");
```

Hello,
I have greasemonkey v3.8 and I want to exclude all "sample.com" url's containing "/php/*"
-How can I do this? For me the description above with "exclude" doesn't work.

Comment: `@exclude     https://www.sample.com/*/php/*` ?

Comment: it seems to be a greasemonkey bug. I edited the description and saved it, but "exclude" didn't work. After I created a new userscript it worked fine with the following description:`// ==UserScript==
// @name        Helloworld
// @namespace   https://www.sample.com
// @exclude     https://www.sample.com/php/*
// ==/UserScript==
alert("HELLO");`